# Option Key + numbers not working

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, alt-code

My problem might be a little bit weird but I couldn't find any solution on the Internet.

I am using Macbook Pro and running Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard.

My keyboard layout is "Turkish QWERTY PC". My problem is that I can not type the special symbols being typed by using Alt(Option)+3 and Alt+4 key which are "#" and dollar sign.

I actually opened Key Viewer and typed Alt+3 combination and it says I typed "#" but I can't.

Is there any solution to fix this? Actually, I really wonder why more.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wait just Option+3 and 4 or 1-0 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was because I set the keyboard shortcut for "Arrow Keys to switch directly to a space" as "Alt(Option) Key + Number keys" in Spaces.app. I don't know why this caused a conflict but after I changed that setting to "Command + Number keys", it resolved.

Thanks again.